# Babel plugin - get structured information as output after static code analysis

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, code-analysis, static-analysis

I am developing a dev tool that would provide me some code metrics.

I would like the tool to go through the source files and count the **usages** (#loc) per **imported value** and per **library**.

I.e. for *lodash*, I would like to know the usages of `isEqual`, `cloneDeep`.
I would like to have as output:

```
+------------+------------+---------+
|   Library  |  Imported  |   #LOC  |
+------------+------------+---------+
| Lodash     | isEqual    |       20|
| Lodash     | cloneDeep  |        4|
+------------+------------+---------+
```

*Example file of what should be found by the tool*

```
1 // aFile.js
2 import {isEqual, cloneDeep} from 'lodash'
3 // some code ..
4 if (isEqual(variableA, variableB)) {
5 //  ^^^^^^^
6 }
7 let myClonedObject = cloneDeep(myObject);
8 //                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

I started the implementation as a babel plugin as I knew it would let me easily

- parse the code in a readable format (AST)
- visit all the importDeclaration
- get the relevant references
- calculate the usages

*current implementation*

```
export default function({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      ImportDeclaration(path, state) {
        if(path.get('source').node.value === 'lodash') {
          path.get('specifiers').forEach(function(specifier) {
            if(specifier.node.imported) {
              const importedIdentifierName = specifier.node.imported.name;
              if(importedIdentifierName === 'isEqual') {
                const isEqualLoc = new Set();
                const {referencePaths} = path.scope.getBinding(importedIdentifierName);
                referencePaths.forEach(function(referencePath) {
                  isEqualLOC.add(referencePath.node.loc.start.line);
                });
                console.log(isEqualLOC.size);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

For this tool, I only do **read** operations on the code (no transform / generate).

**My question**: How can I share the produced information in the babel plugin (lib/import/#loc) to the result of the `babel-cli` command or any other API ?

I thought about logging the result (with a specific id) with `console.log` but it seems to me like a workaround.
I was wondering if there is some clear API on exposing info out of a babel plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like something that might be better off built using Babel's utilities, but implemented on your own base. Babel at the moment doesn't provide any way to output stats or anything. You could for instance change your plugin to a script like

```
const fs = require('fs');
const babylon = require('bablylon');
const traverse = require('babel-traverse');

const data = fs.readFileSync('./thing.js');
traverse(babylon.parse(data), {
  ImportDeclaration(path) {
    // ...
  },
});

// Do whatever output you want here
```

Comment: It makes sense, thanks!
That's the feedback I got from @thejameskyle as well.
I'll try this ASAP and update this answer accordingly.